# Where to see plans for connected account in stripe dashboard?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have created a plan to my Connect Stripe. I can see application fee on my dashboard but I can not see the created plan.

can i see the plans created in my connected account.

Answer (score 0):

Login -> dashboard:
On left side menu, there is the link name Subscription and Connect.

- In connected, you can see you connected account and more details related to it.
- In subscription, you can see plans which you created.